# Node.js Flatiron HTTPS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, flatiron.js

Is there a way of using HTTPS connection with Flatiron framework?

**Updated:**
HTTPS server example is available on [github](https://github.com/flatiron/flatiron#example-https-server) now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var flatiron = require('flatiron'),
    app = flatiron.app;

app.use(flatiron.plugins.http, {
  https: {
    cert: 'path/to/cert.pem',
    key: 'path/to/key.pem',
    ca: 'path/to/ca.pem'
  }
});

app.router.get('/', function () {
  this.res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  this.res.end('Hello world!\n');
});

app.start(8080);
```

Comment: Thank you for merging commits.

Answer (score 2):

Referring the **[docs](https://github.com/flatiron/union#createserveroptions)** looks like https can be added as an option which should look like this

```
{
  https: {
    cert: 'path/to/cert.pem',
    key: 'path/to/key.pem',
    ca: 'path/to/ca.pem'
  }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. I have no idea how I could miss it.